# Error de JavaScript/Jquery "TypeError: Property 'handleEvent' is not callable." ¿Que podra ser?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Bueno hoy estuve practicando y me encontre con este Error reflejado en la Consola:

> TypeError: Property 'handleEvent' is not callable.

Quisiera Saber porque ocurre, dejare mi practica de Formulario por aca para ver si pueden ayudarme a solucionar, me gustaria saber porque sucede y como arreglarlo...

Aca el Codigo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Validacion y animacion en input name
    //Al usuario hacer FOCUS en el input Nombre:
    $('#namei').focusin(function(){
        //Hacer arriba el texto "Nombre" en el Input
        $('#label1').css("top","-10px");
    });
    //Al usuario salir del FOCUS en el input Nombre:
    $('#namei').focusout(function(){
        //Si no hay nada, devolver a estado inicial
        if($(this).val().length == 0){
           //Estado inicial de Css
           $('#label1').css("top","15px");
        };
    });
    //Funcion para verificar el input="namei"
    $('#namei').on('input',function(comprobarNombre){
        //Si no hay nada, devolver a estado inicial
        if($(this).val().length == 0){
            //Remover Clases añadidas si el usuario agrego texto y luego lo borro
            $('#label1').parent().removeClass("error ok");
            //Setear mensaje personalizado de error
            mensaje = "El nombre no puede estar vacío";
        //Si la cantidad de letras es menor a 10 entonces...
        } else if($(this).val().length < 10 ){
            //Añadir Clase "error" para ADVERTIR con un color ROJO (Clase de CSS)
            $('#label1').parent().addClass("error");
            //
            $('#label1').parent().removeClass("ok");
            //
            mensaje = "El nombre es muy corto";
        //Si todo esta bien...
        }else {
            //Remover Clases añadidas si el usuario agrego texto y luego corrigio
            $('#label1').parent().removeClass("error");
            //Añadir Clase "ok" para indicar con un color Verde (Clase de CSS) que todo esta bien
            $('#label1').parent().addClass("ok");
            mensaje = "";
        };
        //Setear validacion personalizada
        this.setCustomValidity(mensaje);
        // cuando se cambie el valor del campo o sea incorrecto, mostrar/resetear mensaje
        this.addEventListener("invalid", comprobarNombre);
        this.addEventListener("input", comprobarNombre);
    });
    //
    //
    //Validacion y animacion en input Correo
    $('#emaili').focusin(function(){
        //Hacer arriba el texto "Correo" en el Input
        $('#label2').css("top","-10px");
    });
    //Devolver el texto "Correo" a su posicion en el Input
    $('#emaili').focusout(function(){
        if($(this).val().length == 0){
            $('#label1').parent().removeClass("error ok");
            $('#label2').css("top","15px");
        };
    });
    //Funcion para verificar el input="namei"
    $('#emaili').on('input',function(comprobarEmail){
        var mensaje = "";
        // comprobar los posibles errores
        if (this.value <= 0) {
            $('#label2').parent().removeClass("error ok");
            mensaje = "El email no puede estar vacío";
        } else if (this.value.indexOf("@") < 0) {
            $('#label2').parent().addClass("error");
            mensaje = "El email debe contener una @";
        } else if (this.value.indexOf(".com", this.value.indexOf("@")) < 0) {
            $('#label2').parent().addClass("error");
            mensaje = "El email debe terminar con '.com'";
        } else {
            $('#label2').parent().removeClass("error");
            $('#label2').parent().addClass("ok");
        }
        // mostrar/resetear mensaje (el mensaje se resetea poniendolo a "")
        this.setCustomValidity(mensaje);
        // cuando se cambie el valor del campo o sea incorrecto, mostrar/resetear mensaje
        this.addEventListener("invalid", comprobarEmail);
        this.addEventListener("input", comprobarEmail);
    });
    //
    //
    //Validacion y animacion Telefono
    $('#teli').focusin(function(){
        //Hacer arriba el texto "Correo" en el Input
        $('#label3').css("top","-10px");
    });
    //Devolver el texto "Correo" a su posicion en el Input
    $('#teli').focusout(function(){
        if($(this).val().length == 0){
            $('#label3').css("top","15px");
        };
    });
    //
    $('#teli').on('input',function(){
        if($(this).val().length == 0){
            $('#label3').parent().removeClass("ok error");
        }else if($(this).val().length < 10 ){
            //Añadir Clase "error" para ADVERTIR con un color ROJO (Clase de CSS)
            $('#label3').parent().addClass("error");
            //
            $('#label3').parent().removeClass("ok");
            //
            mensaje = "El numero es muy corto";
        }else {
            //Remover Clases añadidas si el usuario agrego texto y luego corrigio
            $('#label3').parent().removeClass("error");
            //Añadir Clase "ok" para indicar con un color Verde (Clase de CSS) que todo esta bien
            $('#label3').parent().addClass("ok");
            mensaje = "";
        };
    });
    //
    //
    //
    $('#texta').on('input', function(){
        if($(this).val().length == 0){
            $('textarea').css('border','2px solid var(--ULine)');
        }else if($(this).val().length < 30 ){
            //Añadir Clase "error" para ADVERTIR con un color ROJO (Clase de CSS)
            $('textarea').css('border','2px solid var(--Error)');
        }else {
            //Añadir Clase "ok" para indicar con un color Verde (Clase de CSS) que todo esta bien
            $('textarea').css('border','2px solid var(--OK)');
        };
    });
    //
    //
    //Validacion CheckBox y boton de Enviar
    $('#btn-form').on('click',function(event){
        var namein = $('#namei').is(":valid");
        var emailin = $('#emaili').is(":valid");
        var texta = $('#labtexta').is('valid');
        var telin = $('#teli').is('valid');
        var terms = $('#terminos').is(":checked");
        if(!namein && !terms && !emailin && !texta){
            if(!namein){
                event.preventDefault();
                $('#label1').parent().addClass("error");
            };
            if(!terms){
                event.preventDefault();
                $('#terminos').parent().addClass("errorc");
            };
            if(!emailin){
                event.preventDefault();
                $('#label2').parent().addClass("error");
            };
            if(!texta){
                event.preventDefault();
                $('textarea').css('border','2px solid var(--Error)');
            };
            if(!telin){
                event.preventDefault();
                $('#label3').parent().addClass("error");
            };
        };
    });
});
```

```css
/*Variables del tema CSS*/
:root {
    /*Variables de Color*/
    --MColor: #00A4DB;
    --FontB: #262626;
    --FontW: #FCFCFC;
    --LBackColor: #EDF6FF;
    --BackColor: #c7f1ff;
    --CBackColor: #a0e7ff;
    --DarkColor: #0091c2;
    --SDarkColor: #006b8f;
    --UDarkColor: #003d52;
    --ULine: #29c9ff;
    --Warning: #ff6b00;
    --Error: #f02000;
    --Def: #c5c5c5;
    --OK: #00bd68;
    /*Otras Variables*/
    --FontF: 'Roboto';
    --FontS: 20px;
    --FontSU: 24px;
    --FontSM: 16px;
    --FontSN: 12px;
    --bormin: 2px;
}
.cont {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px 50px 50px 50px;
}
/*Div Formulario*/
.contform {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
    padding: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    margin: auto;
    background: var(--BackColor);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px grey;
}
    .form {
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .input_group {
        margin-bottom: 32px;
        position: relative;
    }
    .contform h2 {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: var(--FontSU);
        margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
    }
    #h2i {
        margin: 60px 0px 0px 0px;
        font-size: var(--FontSN);
    }
    hr {
        border: none;
        border-bottom: 2px solid var(--DarkColor);
        margin: 40px auto;
        width: 90%;
    }
/*Cambios Generales para la etiqueta <input> para estilo Material Desing*/
input[type="text"],
input[type="tel"],
input[type="email"] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 1px;
    margin: 8px 0px;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid var(--Def);
    font-family: var(--FontF);
    font-size: var(--FontSM);
    color: var(--UDarkColor);
    /*Transicion opcional*/
    transition: 1s all ease;
}
    /*Cambio de estilos al estar en foco del usuario*/
    input:focus,
    input:active {
        border-bottom: 1px solid var(--ULine);
    }
    .error input {
        border-bottom: 1px solid var(--Error);
        color: var(--Error);
    }   
    .error  label {
        color: var(--Error);
    }
    .ok label {
        color: var(--OK);
    }
    .ok input {
        border-bottom: 1px solid var(--OK);
        color: var(--OK);
    }
    .label {
        color: var(--UDarkColor);
        position: absolute;
        top: 15px;
        left: 1px;
        font-size: var(--FontSM);
        line-height: 18px;
        cursor: text;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }
.mylabel {
    top: -15px;
}
/*Cambio de tema para los Radio Buttons y Checkboxes*/
.checkbox label,
.radio label {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: var(--Mcolor);
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 51px;
    font-size: 1em;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    margin: auto;
}
    .checkbox label:hover,
    .radio label:hover {
        background: rgba(0,147,169,0.2);
    }
    .checkbox label:before,
    .radio label:before {
        content: "";
        display: inline-block;
        width: 17px;
        height: 17px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 15px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: none;
        border: 3px solid var(--DarkColor);
    }
    .errorc label {
        background: rgba(240, 32, 0, 0.3)
    }
    input[type="radio"],
    input[type="checkbox"] {
        display: none;
    }
    input[type="radio"]:checked + label:before,
    input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
        display: none;
    }
    input[type="radio"]:checked + label, 
    input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
        padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
        background: var(--MColor);
        margin: auto;
    }
    .input_group {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        width: 100%;
    }
textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    border: 2px solid var(--ULine);
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    font-size: 16px;
    resize: none;
}
#labtexta {
    color: var(--UDarkColor);
    font-size: var(--FontSM);
}
/*Cambios de estilo para el Bonto "ENVIAR"*/
input[type="submit"] {
    background: var(--UDarkColor);
    border-radius: 1px;
    border: 2px solid var(--MColor);
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: var(--FontSU);
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background: var(--DarkColor);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
        <div class="cont">         
            <!--Formulario Estilo Material Desing-->
            <div class="contform">
            <h2>FORMULARIO DE CONTACTO</h2>
            <form action="" class="formulario" name="Contacto" method="get" autocomplete="off">
                <div class="form">
                    <!--Inputs De Informacion Perosnal-->
                    <div class="input_group">
                        <input type="text" id="namei" name="nombre" required pattern=".{10,}">
                        <label class="label" id="label1" for="namei">Nombre y Apellido:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input_group">
                        <input type="email" id="emaili" name="correo" required>
                        <label class="label" id="label2" for="emaili">Correo:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input_group">
                        <input type="tel" id="teli" name="numero"  minlength="5" maxlength="30">
                        <label class="label" id="label3" for="teli">Telefono (opcional):</label>
                    </div>
                    <!--Inputs De Cuadro de Texto-->
                    <div class="input_group">
                        <label for="texta" id="labtexta">Texto a Enviar:</label>
                        <textarea name="Texto" id="texta" cols="30" rows="10" required maxlength="300" minlength="30"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <!--Inputs De Verificación-->
                    <div class="input_group checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="terminos" id="terminos" value="true">
                        <label for="terminos">Acepto Los Terminos Y Condiciones</label>
                    </div>
                    <!--Boton de Envio-->
                    <input type="submit" id="btn-form" value="Enviar">
                    <!--Informacion extra-->
                    <h2 id="h2i">Jorge Acosta</h2> <br>
                    <a href="#">LEA NUESTRO TERMINOS Y CONDICIONES</a>
                </div>
            </form>
            </div>    
        </div>
```

EDICIÓN:

El error sucede solo al escribir sobre alguno de los Inputs, no importa cualquiera que sea, igual muestra el error al tipear cualquier cosa.

EDICIÓN 2:

Al parecer el error no se hace visible ante ustedes ¿se estara escondiendo? bueno dejo por aca ina imagen para que vean lo que me sucede :c

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ese código que pusiste no muestra ningún error.

Comment: `EDICIÓN:El error sucede solo al escribir sobre alguno de los Inputs, no importa cualquiera que sea, igual muestra el error al tipear cualquier cosa.`

Comment: Parece funcionar sin problemas. He completado el formulario y se ha enviado bien.

Comment: Lo probe local y sigue funcionando, presiona Shift + F5 para refrescar el navegador. E intentalo de nuevo

Comment: El problema es que estás intentando llamar a una propiedad como si fuera una función (con los paréntesis, algo que ocurre a veces si defines una variable con el mismo nombre de un método). El error parece ocurrir en una parte del código que no has compartido y por eso nosotros no lo vemos. Lee sobre cómo crear un [mcve] y comparte el código relevante a la pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al parecer es un error que solo ocurre en `Firefox`. He probado con Chrome y no aparace el error, sin embargo tambien luego de eleer un comentario sobre el llamado de una propiedad como funcion me puse a comentar todos los posibles llamados y pues al parecer e dado con el problema, en efecto es el llamado de propiedad como si fuese una funcion, este error esta en las siguientes lineas:

```
$('#namei').on('input',function(comprobarNombre){
    //Si no hay nada, devolver a estado inicial
    if($(this).val().length == 0){
        //Remover Clases añadidas si el usuario agrego texto y luego lo borro
        $('#label1').parent().removeClass("error ok");
        //Setear mensaje personalizado de error
        mensaje = "El nombre no puede estar vacío";
    //Si la cantidad de letras es menor a 10 entonces...
    } else if($(this).val().length < 10 ){
        //Añadir Clase "error" para ADVERTIR con un color ROJO (Clase de CSS)
        $('#label1').parent().addClass("error");
        //
        $('#label1').parent().removeClass("ok");
        //
        mensaje = "El nombre es muy corto";
    //Si todo esta bien...
    }else {
        //Remover Clases añadidas si el usuario agrego texto y luego corrigio
        $('#label1').parent().removeClass("error");
        //Añadir Clase "ok" para indicar con un color Verde (Clase de CSS) que todo esta bien
        $('#label1').parent().addClass("ok");
        mensaje = "";
    };
    //Setear validacion personalizada
    this.setCustomValidity(mensaje);
    // cuando se cambie el valor del campo o sea incorrecto, mostrar/resetear mensaje
    this.addEventListener("invalid", comprobarNombre);
    this.addEventListener("input", comprobarNombre);
});
```

El problema esta en:

```
$('#namei').on('input',function (comprobarNombre){
```

Ya que este codigo `this.addEventListener("invalid", comprobarNombre);
    this.addEventListener("input", comprobarNombre);` esta esta llamando a `comprobarNombre` cuando este esta como un parametro en la función. Al corregir, ya no me aparece el error (Cabe destacar que por esto amo Firefox Sobre Chrome, puesto que en Chrome Nunca aparecio este error).

Al final la solución es:

```
$('#namei').on('input',function comprobarNombre(){
```

Al igual con el Input de Email:

```
$('#namei').on('input',function comprobarEmail(){
```

Muchas Gracias a todos los que me han ayudado a dar con el problema! Gracias